# WCF Service is showing error after implemented in IIS

Tags: wcf, iis-7, enterprise-library, data-access

In my project I am using Enterprise Library to connect to database. It is working fine when I run the application from Visual Studio directly.

But this is showing error connecting to database when hosted in IIS on same machine. I have added log trace and got the following error

> Resolution of the dependency failed, type =
>   "Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database", name =
>   "(none)". Exception occurred while: while resolving. Exception is:
>   InvalidOperationException - The type Database cannot be constructed.
>   You must configure the container to supply this value.
>   ----------------------------------------------- At the time of the
>   exception, the container was:
>
> Resolving Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database,(none)
>   | Exception:Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException:
>   Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type
>   Database, key "" --->
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the
>   dependency failed, type =
>   "Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database", name =
>   "(none)". Exception occurred while: while resolving. Exception is:
>   InvalidOperationException - The type Database cannot be constructed.
>   You must configure the container to supply this value.
>   ----------------------------------------------- At the time of the
>   exception, the container was:
>
> Resolving Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database,(none)
>   ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The type Database cannot be
>   constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value.
>   at
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodConstructorStrategy.GuardTypeIsNonPrimitive(IBuilderContext
>   context, SelectedConstructor selectedConstructor)    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodConstructorStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlanCreatorPolicy.CreatePlan(IBuilderContext
>   context, NamedTypeBuildKey buildKey)    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context)    at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type
>   t, Object existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides)
>
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object
>   existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides)    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, String
>   name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides)    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type
>   serviceType, String key)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at
>   Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type
>   serviceType, String key)    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance[TService](String
>   key)    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.DatabaseFactory.InnerCreateDatabase(String
>   name)

My `web.config` of service is contains as below

```
<configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
    <section name="dataConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data"/>
  </configSections>
<dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="OracleConnection">
    <providerMappings>
      <add databaseType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Oracle.OracleDatabase, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data" name="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"/>
    </providerMappings>
  </dataConfiguration>
  <connectionStrings>
      <add name="OracleConnection" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" connectionString="User Id=***;Password=****;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=*****)(PORT=1500)) (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME =*****)));"/>
<add name="SybaseConnection" connectionString="providerName=Sybase.ASEOLEDBProvider;Server=****;Port=5050;Catalog=**;User Id=***;Password=****"/>
      </connectionStrings>
```

I tried a lot but unable to find the cause of issue. :(

I checked the permission on the folder and Everyone has full control. WCF Service in IIS Anonymous access is enabled.

Could anyone please help?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a WCF-related issue.  It appears to be an issue with the Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data assembly.  Have you checked the database setup?

Comment: Yes. With the same code and same dlls this is workign fine when running from Visual studio directly. Problem occurs only when implemented in IIS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i enabled 32 bit applications in IIS the error has been changed to

> ORA-12638: Credential retrieval failed

The connection string is correct which is working with visual studio.

Is there any setting we need to do in Oralce part to acces connection from IIS?

This worked fine when updated sqlnet.ora file of oracle.

Answer (score 1):

The assembly you are using cannot find one of the assemblies it depends on, make sure all dependencies are either in the GAC or in the bin folder of your web app.

Comment: Thanks Jon, But how can i identify which all are dependent dlls? More over it is working fine when running directly from Visual studio. Why the problem comes in IIS?

Comment: I have apps do this from time to time, and it has to do with the way visual studio deploys the binaries in your bin folder. Sometimes it doesn't pick up all of them. Also, sometimes the search path is a little different. To identify the dependencies, I would try looking at the documentation for the assembly. Also make sure that the bin folder in your deployed app looks identical to the bin folder in your visual studio app.

Comment: When i enabled 32 bit applications in IIS the error has been changed to

    ORA-12638: Credential retrieval failed

The connection string is correct which is working with visual studio.

Is there any setting we need to do in Oralce part to acces connection from IIS?

Comment: @Hari Are you using windows authentication? If so, the problem may be because the iis user doesn't have access. Try impersonating your user which you know works in your web.config file.